# Set oracle database default nls_sort in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am using `ALTER SESSION SET nls_sort=persian` in my session for correcting my sort in Persian language.

How can I set this parameter as default. means for all sessions

Answer (score 2):

You can create a trigger to run that alter statement after a successful login.

According to the Internet this can also be defaulted by modifying an environment variable as well.

Both methods are mentioned/described here... https://forums.oracle.com/thread/924804

Specifically:

```
Set with an operating system environment variable 
Windows: SET NLS_SORT=value
*nix: setenv NLS_SORT value
or execute this after each login (this can be put on logon trigger)
```

Answer (score 0):

NLS_SORT's default value is assigned as value of NLS_LANGUAGE. So if you want the entire database language and other formats in persian then change the NLS_LANG value.

Else If you want to change only NLS_SORT vlaue then go with carters idea or create a script which will set all default NLS_ values on session start.